# How to Prevent Title Bar from Auto-Showing When Switching Between Full Screen Spaces on macOS?

Tags: macos, settings, window-manager, spaces, system-settings

On macOS Sonoma (version 14.2.1), I encounter an issue where the application's title bar automatically shows up each time I switch between full screen apps across different spaces. This behavior is unnecessary and distracting for me.

I'm seeking a method to prevent the title bar from automatically appearing during these transitions. Ideally, the title bar should remain hidden or only become visible when I move my cursor to the top edge of the screen, specifically not during space switching.

Does anyone know of a setting or workaround to stop this auto-show behavior of the title bar in full screen mode on macOS (Sonoma)?